# replace loops with vector operations

Tags: python, pandas

This is an example of a problem I need to solve.
I have 2 tables
And I have to find a substring(dff2) in a string(dff). And if substring in a string exists add this row to the output dataframe.
The problem is that I wrote the code using loops and it works too slow for thousands of rows. How could I rewrite the code using pandas methods?

```
data = {'long string column': ['aaaabbbbccccdddd', 'bbbbccccddddeeee','ccccddddeeeeffff','ddddeeeeffffgggg'],}
dff = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['long string column'])


data2 = {'substring_column': ['aaaa', 'bbbb','cccc','dddd'], 'status': ['best', 'good','bad','worst'],}
dff2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['substring_column','status'])


df_output = pd.DataFrame()
df_output_small = pd.DataFrame()


for i in range(len(dff2)):
    df_output_small = dff[(dff['long string column'].str.contains(dff2['substring_column'].iloc[i]))]
                          
    df_output_small['status'] = dff2['status'].iloc[i]

    df_output = df_output.append(df_output_small, ignore_index=True)
                          
df_output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for all substrings and then right `merge`:

```
pat = f'({"|".join(dff2["substring_column"])})'
```

If there are some substrings which should be regexes use `re.escape`:

```
import re
pat = '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in dff2['substring_column'])
```

---

```
df = (dff.set_index('long string column', drop=False)['long string column']
         .str.extractall(pat)[0]
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='substring_column'))
df = df.merge(dff2, on='substring_column', how='right')
print (df)
  long string column substring_column status
0   aaaabbbbccccdddd             aaaa   best
1   aaaabbbbccccdddd             bbbb   good
2   bbbbccccddddeeee             bbbb   good
3   aaaabbbbccccdddd             cccc    bad
4   bbbbccccddddeeee             cccc    bad
5   ccccddddeeeeffff             cccc    bad
6   aaaabbbbccccdddd             dddd  worst
7   bbbbccccddddeeee             dddd  worst
8   ccccddddeeeeffff             dddd  worst
9   ddddeeeeffffgggg             dddd  worst
```

Last remove `substring_column` column:

```
df = df.drop('substring_column', axis=1)
```

Comment: It worked for the example I wrote above but it raises an error for subsrings like that 'aa(aa'  (says missing ")" ). Unfortunately I have such stupid substrings in my problem. How would I rewrite the code? P.S. Anyway thank you for helping. And as your code workds for wxample I confirm it!)